# Drupal - Send email notification when admin change attribute of node

Tags: email, drupal, drupal-7, notifications, watchdog

I'm trying to find a way, how to create email notification. I have content type "Item" with price attribute.

First I need to add possibility to sign in some email to created content - some kind of watchdog - I don't want to be registered as a new user to be able to add email. And if admin update price of this content, I need to send email to all registered emails (registered emails only for updated content)

How can I create this watchdog? Is there any module?

Thanks a lot
Martin

Answer (score 1):

You can use [rules](https://drupal.org/project/rules). This module allows you to react on events.

Comment: And how can I collect emails to content? For example I'm anonymous user and I want to watch my product and its price. If admin change the price of this product, I want recieve info email.

Comment: You have to create an event on node save with a condition specifying that just trigger that action on the content type that you want and then trigger the action send mail to that user. If that make sense. Anyway if you play with the rules module you will be able to do it.

Comment: I worte it incorrectly. What is the best way to achieve an email collection? Create another content type just for emails, and this content type will be related to my product (via entity reference)? But there will be no functionality for signing up visitors emails. Or is there any better way (any module,...)?

Comment: I don't know if it's the best way but I think that you can use the module [field collection](https://drupal.org/project/field_collection) to achieve that behaviour.